# Query to get record id if exists in any table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these 4 tables, they are to store user item.

The item is unique and can only exists one table at a time.

Also, I am searching using serial column

```
users:
======
id
name

user_bags:
==========
id
user_id
serial


user_store:
===========
id
user_id
serial

user_storage:
============
id
user_id
serial
```

I have a list of item and need to search them whether they are in any table and show the id for the record in that table.

```
user_name |   user_bags   |    user_store   |    user_storage    |      
==================================================================
A         |     2390      |                 |                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
B         |               |        352      |                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
A         |     5500      |                 |                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------
C         |               |                 |         6440       |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT
     users.name AS user_name,
     (SELECT id FROM user_bags WHERE user_bags.serial = 'abc' AND user_bags.user_id = users.id) AS user_bags,
     (SELECT id FROM user_storage WHERE user_storage.serial = 'abc' AND user_storage.user_id = users.id) AS user_storage,
     (SELECT id FROM user_store WHERE user_store.serial = 'abc' AND user_store.user_id = users.id) AS user_store
FROM
     users
```

How do I do a better query (faster)? and a proper one. I will be looking through several thousand serial and there are million of records in each table at at time.

## Updated: And only show with user having found a match

Comment: This won't work if the item appears more than once in a given table.

Comment: updated my question. item is unique, and can only exists in 1 table at a time

Comment: This seems more like a normalization issue than anything else to me. You have multiple tables that are identical but each mean something else. This seems like it should be two tables. One for Users and another for UserItems which would be like your current tables but with an additional column to indicate which type of item. With your current structure if you add a new item type you have have add a new table and subsequently update every query that touches them.

Comment: @SeanLange it is a legacy DB

Comment: Legacy or not the biggest issues problem seems to be normalization. I get it though. Sometimes we have to plug our nose and plow forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is fine.  For performance, you want indexes on `(user_id, serial, id)` in the three tables used in the subqueries.

With the indexes, a `left join` would probably have equivalent performance:

```
select u.name, ub.id as user_bags, us.id as user_storage, ust.id as user_store
from users u left join
     user_bags ub
     on ub.serial = 'abc' and ub.user_id = u.id left join
     user_storage us
     on us.serial = 'abc' and us.user_id = u.id left join
     user_store ust
     on ust.serial = 'abc' and ust.user_id = u.id
from users;
```

Comment: I am really sorry, but I have an updated question at the end, how to show only the one that has result/findings.

Comment: @rfpdl . . . That doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the best I can do with the given information.

Let me restructure / standardize this a little for you.

```
SELECT users.name AS [user_name],
    user_bags.id AS user_bags,
    user_storage.id AS user_storage,
    user_store.id AS user_store
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_store ON user_store.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN user_bags ON user_bags.user_id = users.id AND user_bags.serial = user_store.serial
LEFT JOIN user_storage ON user_storage.user_id = users.id AND user_storage.serial = user_store.serial
WHERE user_store.serial = 'abc'
```

Make sure that you have covering indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_users_ID ON Users ( ID )
CREATE INDEX IX_user_store_ID_Serial ON user_store ( ID, serial )
CREATE INDEX IX_user_bags_ID_Serial ON user_bags ( ID, serial )
CREATE INDEX IX_user_storage_ID_Serial ON user_storage ( ID, serial )
```

There are ways to improve performance from here but I would need to know the tables, see query plans and know their perspective record counts.